# Why do I need an A and AAAA record in addition to MX record for my mail server?

Tags: postfix, email-server, dovecot

**Environment:** Postfix, Dovecot, CentOS, Digital Ocean droplet

**DNS Records:**

```
Type: A
Hostname: mail.example.com
Value: 1.1.1.1

Type: AAAA
Hostname: mail.example.com
Value: 1000:1:1:1:1:1:0001

Type: MX
Hostname: example.com
Value: mail.example.com

Type: TXT
Hostname: example.com
Value: returns v=spf1 a ~all

Type: TXT
Hostname: _dmarc.example.com
Value: v=DMARC1; p=quarantine;

Type: TXT
Hostname: 111111._domainkey.example.com
Value: returns v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=abcde12345...
```

**Background:** My mail server sends and receives email as expected and (I hope) is secure.

**Question:** Why is it required that I use an A and a AAAA record for my mail server in addition to the MX record?  Isn't the MX record designed to handle all email requests?  In addition although I don't believe my server is throwing any errors do I need any sort of additional MX records to make this robust?  I'm not an expert on MX records and I'm not sure if a single record is a best practice.

Comment: If you didn't have one, how would anyone know what the IP for `mail.example.com` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MX record designates the host that is authoritative for email for your domain. In order for servers to send email to that host you need to have a host record for it (A record).

Comment: So if I understand you correctly the A and AAAA records tell the world that mail.example.com sits at a specific IP address.  Once the request gets there the MX record is used to forward the request to the mail server?  If so that makes sense.  Why is the Hostname of the MX record `example.com` instead of `mail.example.com`?  It works fine but it seems weird to me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an email sent to person@example.com. That MX record for example.com delegates mail to mail.example.com. AAAA and A records are to resolve that mail host name to IP.

Or, the address could easily be person@mail.example.com, MX record of mail.example.com. Technically, this should work with the records you provided, because the fallback if no MX record is to look up any AAAA or A records of that name.

However, modern convention is to keep it short. Users are accustomed to "local at domain dot TLD". Subdomains continue to be useful where there are different email systems for non-technical reasons, like at universities or very large enterprises.